# Performance: Loop incl. AJAX vs. a single request with php loop

Tags: php, ajax, performance, loops

I wrote a PHP that is currently looping through data, validating and importing them into a database. This can take some time, depending on the amount of data to run through.

My next step is to make this "user-friendly" so others can use it, not just me. I was looking at the components I want to implement, including a progress bar so the user knows the script isn't just stuck but is doing something.

Now the question comes up: should I use a JavaScript loop through the data, have them validated one by one and imported to the database with the help of an AJAX call to my php script? This would be pretty useful as well to update the progress bar after each iteration.

Or is it—performance-wise—better to do a single request to the php script which then loops through the data? In that case: how could I implement the updating progress bar?

These are a bunch of questions. The overall purpose is to see what my options are and what arguments speak for each. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to have a progress bar, then you will need to do it 1-by-1, you would count all the records and then very time one calls back as completed, you would increment the progress bar by a certain percentage.

```
100 / amount of records = percentage to increase progress bar.
```

However, the issue with that approach is that if somewhere along the line it fails, you will need to know where it did so, or devise a way to make sure duplicates are not added to the database (If that's even an issue).

It would be better to add the data at once, faster and cleaner, but it would remove the possibility of having a progress bar that actually gives you a correct progress report.

Comment: Thanks Harry, valid point. However, no matter if I use Javascript or the PHP script that does the looping, either way I would have a problem if it fails. To ensure no duplicates are entered would have to be verified another way I guess.